# How to get this into Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am a newbie at Kotlin and have been praticing Android for months now . I am stuck at converting this code from Java to Kotlin . The declaration syntax of args is out of my understanding.How can I convert below piece of code to Kotlin?

```
 public static boolean validate(EditText... editTexts){
        EditText nameTxt = editTexts[0];
        EditText descriptionTxt = editTexts[1];
        EditText galaxyTxt = editTexts[2];
        return true;
}
```

Thank-You in advance

Comment: You can write your static methods in companion object while using kotlin

Comment: i don't know why you would want to pass around a bunch of edit texts to a method

Comment: For validations

Comment: (i'm not the downvoter) i don't know why you would want to pass them around seeing as though they can just be variables you access in this class, you can create [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) for these edit texts to be used for validation as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
validate(EditText... editTexts)
```

you must use this in kotlin (**vararg**)

```
validate(vararg editTexts: EditText)
```

So full code in kotlin is

```
   fun validate(vararg editTexts: EditText): Boolean {
        val nameTxt = editTexts[0]
        val descriptionTxt = editTexts[1]
        val galaxyTxt = editTexts[2]
        return true
    }
```

Source [variable-number-of-arguments-varargs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Java to Kotlin**

> ```
> fun validate(vararg editTexts: EditText): Boolean {    
>     val nameTxt = editTexts[0]    
>     val descriptionTxt = editTexts[1]    
>     val galaxyTxt = editTexts[2]    
>     return true
> }
> ```

2. To make it **static**, wrap it within **companion object**

> ```
> companion object {
>     fun validate(vararg editTexts: EditText): Boolean {    
>         val nameTxt = editTexts[0]    
>         val descriptionTxt = editTexts[1]    
>         val galaxyTxt = editTexts[2]    
>         return true
>     } 
> }
> ```